# How to optimize filter for big data volume? PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, postgresql-11

A few weeks ago our team faced difficulties with our SQL query because the data volume has increased a lot.
We would appreciate any advice on how we can update schema or optimize the query in order to keep `status` filtering logic the same.

In a nutshell:
We have two tables `a` and `b`. `b` has FK to `a` as M-1.

## a

```
id | processed

1    TRUE

2    TRUE
```

## b

```
a_id| status | type_id | l_id 

1     '1'      5          105  

1     '3'      6          105 

2     '2'      7          105
```

We can have only one status for a unique combination of (`l_id`, `type_id`, `a_id`).

We need to calculate count of `a` rows filtered by statuses from `b` grouped by `a_id` . 
In table `a` we have 5 300 000  rows.
In table `b` 750 000 000 rows.

So we need to calculate status for each `a` row  by the next rules:
For a_id there are x rows in `b`:

1) If at least one status of x equals '3', then status for `a_id` is '3'.

2) If all statuses of x equal `1` then the status is `1`.

And so on.

In current approach we use array_agg() function for filtering of subselection. So our query looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
       SELECT
       FROM (
              SELECT at.id                         as id,
                     BOOL_AND(bt.processed)        AS not_pending,
                     ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT bt.status) AS status
              FROM a AS at
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN b AS bt
                                     ON (at.id = bt.a_id AND bt.l_id = 105 AND
                                         bt.type_id IN (2,10,18,1,4,5,6))
              WHERE at.processed = True
              GROUP BY at.id) sub
       WHERE not_pending = True
         AND status <@ ARRAY ['1']::"char"[]
     ) counter
;
```

Our plan looks like:

```
Aggregate  (cost=14665999.33..14665999.34 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1875987.846..1875987.846 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=14166691.70..14599096.58 rows=5352220 width=37) (actual time=1875987.844..1875987.844 rows=0 loops=1)
        Group Key: at.id
        Filter: (bool_and(bt.processed) AND (array_agg(DISTINCT bt.status) <@ '{1}'::"char"[]))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 5353930
        ->  Sort  (cost=14166691.70..14258067.23 rows=36550213 width=6) (actual time=1860315.593..1864175.762 rows=37430745 loops=1)
              Sort Key: at.id
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 586000kB
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1135654.48..8076230.39 rows=36550213 width=6) (actual time=55665.584..1846965.271 rows=37430745 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (bt.a_id = at.id)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on b bt  (cost=882095.79..7418660.65 rows=36704370 width=6) (actual time=51871.658..1826058.186 rows=37430378 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: ((l_id = 105) AND (type_id = ANY ('{2,10,18,1,4,5,6}'::integer[])))
                          Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 574462752
                          Heap Blocks: exact=28898 lossy=5726508
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on db_page_index_atableobjects  (cost=0.00..872919.69 rows=36704370 width=0) (actual time=51861.815..51861.815 rows=37586483 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((l_id = 105) AND (type_id = ANY ('{2,10,18,1,4,5,6}'::integer[])))
                    ->  Hash  (cost=165747.94..165747.94 rows=5352220 width=4) (actual time=3791.710..3791.710 rows=5353930 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 131072  Batches: 128  Memory Usage: 2507kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on a at  (cost=0.00..165747.94 rows=5352220 width=4) (actual time=0.528..2958.004 rows=5353930 loops=1)
                                Filter: processed
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 18659
Planning time: 0.328 ms
Execution time: 1876066.242 ms
```

As you see the time for the query execution is immense and we would like to make it at least <30 seconds. 
We have already tried some approaches like using bitor() instead of array_agg() and LATERAL JOIN. But they didn't give us desired performance and we decided to use materialized views for now. But we are still in search for any other solution and would really appreciate any suggestions!

Plan with `track_io_timing` enabled:

```
Aggregate  (cost=14665999.33..14665999.34 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2820945.285..2820945.285 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=23 read=5998844, temp read=414465 written=414880
  I/O Timings: read=2655805.505
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=14166691.70..14599096.58 rows=5352220 width=930) (actual time=2820945.283..2820945.283 rows=0 loops=1)
        Group Key: at.id
        Filter: (bool_and(bt.processed) AND (array_agg(DISTINCT bt.status) <@ '{1}'::"char"[]))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 5353930
        Buffers: shared hit=23 read=5998844, temp read=414465 written=414880
        I/O Timings: read=2655805.505
        ->  Sort  (cost=14166691.70..14258067.23 rows=36550213 width=6) (actual time=2804900.123..2808826.358 rows=37430745 loops=1)
              Sort Key: at.id
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 586000kB
              Buffers: shared hit=18 read=5998840, temp read=414465 written=414880
              I/O Timings: read=2655805.491
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1135654.48..8076230.39 rows=36550213 width=6) (actual time=55370.788..2791441.542 rows=37430745 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (bt.a_id = at.id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=15 read=5998840, temp read=142879 written=142625
                    I/O Timings: read=2655805.491
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on b bt  (cost=882095.79..7418660.65 rows=36704370 width=6) (actual time=51059.047..2769127.810 rows=37430378 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: ((l_id = 105) AND (type_id = ANY ('{2,10,18,1,4,5,6}'::integer[])))
                          Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 574462752
                          Heap Blocks: exact=28898 lossy=5726508
                          Buffers: shared hit=13 read=5886842
                          I/O Timings: read=2653254.939
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on db_page_index_atableobjects  (cost=0.00..872919.69 rows=36704370 width=0) (actual time=51049.365..51049.365 rows=37586483 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((l_id = 105) AND (type_id = ANY ('{2,10,18,1,4,5,6}'::integer[])))
                                Buffers: shared hit=12 read=131437
                                I/O Timings: read=49031.671
                    ->  Hash  (cost=165747.94..165747.94 rows=5352220 width=4) (actual time=4309.761..4309.761 rows=5353930 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 131072  Batches: 128  Memory Usage: 2507kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=2 read=111998, temp written=15500
                          I/O Timings: read=2550.551
                          ->  Seq Scan on a at  (cost=0.00..165747.94 rows=5352220 width=4) (actual time=0.515..3457.040 rows=5353930 loops=1)
                                Filter: processed
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 18659
                                Buffers: shared hit=2 read=111998
                                I/O Timings: read=2550.551
Planning time: 0.347 ms
Execution time: 2821022.622 ms
```

Comment: What is the current value of work_mem ? You could try to increase a lot it but only in the current session to reduce recheck cond step.

Comment: How much did the data size increase from when the performance was acceptable to now?  2 fold?  10,000 fold?  Do you have the plan from the query on that old data?

Comment: @pifor, For now, we think more about possibilities to optimize, not to scale.

Comment: @jjanes
 Hi! Sorry for such late feedback.
1)Currently, it is not a real data volume from production. We decided to generate data to test how our current infrastructure and application will work. Currently, we use db.r5.xlarge AWS RDS instance with 2 cores, 32GB RAM and 4 vCPU.

Comment: @jjanes the plan with `track_io_timing` enabled is attached in updated body of question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current plan, substantially all of the time is going to reading the table pages for the Bitmap Heap Scan.  You must already have an index on something like `(l_id, type_id)`.  If you change it (create a new, then optionally drop the old one) to by on `(ld_id, type_id, processed, a_id, status)` instead, or perhaps on `(ld_id, type_id, a_id, status) where processed)`, then it can probably switch to an index-only scan which can avoid reading the table as all the data is present in the index.  You will need to make sure the table is well-vacuumed for this stategy to be effective.  I would just manually vacuum the table once before building the index, then if it works you can at that point worry about how to keep it well-vacuumed.

Another option would be to jack up effective_io_concurrency (I'd just set it to 20.  If it works; you can play with it more to find the optimal setting), so that more than one IO read request on the table can be outstanding at once.  How effective this will be will depend on your IO system, and I don't know the answer to that for db.r5.xlarge.  The index-only scan is better though as it uses less resources, while this method just uses the same resources faster.  (If you have multiple similar queries running simultaneously, that is important.  Also, if you are paying per IO, you want fewer of them, not the same number faster)

Another option is try to change the shape of the plan completely by having a nested loop from a into b.  For this to have a hope, you will need an index on b which contains a_id and l_id as the leading columns (in either order).  If you already have such an index and it doesn't naturally choose such a plan, you might be able to force by `set enable_hashjoin=off.`  My gut feeling this is that a nested loop which needs to kick the other side 5,353,930 times is not going to be better than what you currently have, even if that other side has an efficient index.

Comment: Thank you a lot! You really helped us as much as it was possible xD
We have run the vacuum and rebuilt the index and now it works fine. I don't know why but I haven't even think about running `VACUUM ANALYZE` before the index build.
I believe the problem was because we generated new data in table, but PostgreSQL didn't reanalize the changes and built plan without new information.
Now our plan uses `Index-Only scan` and it takes ~ 10 seconds for 1 type_id in `IN` clause. The only problem now that it takes as more  time as more `type_id` are presented in the condition.

Comment: I am not sure that we can optimize it somehow, maybe increasing CPU or memory will be only one possible solution, will check.
Regarding the keeping DB well-vacuumed. Do you have any first-hand experience with that or maybe any suggestions for us? As I understand we can configure `AUTOVACUUM` for `b` to be a bit stricter and then it should help but are there any recommendations on its configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter and group table B before joining it with A. And order both tables by ID, because it increases speed of table scan when join operation is processed. Please check this code:

```
with at as (
select distinct at.id, at.processed
from a AS at
WHERE at.processed = True
order by at.id
),

bt as (
select bt.a_id, bt.l_id, bt.type_id, --BOOL_AND(bt.processed) AS not_pending, 
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT bt.status) as status
from b AS bt
group by bt.a_id, bt.l_id, bt.type_id
having bt.l_id = 105 AND bt.type_id IN (2,10,18,1,4,5,6)
order by bt.a_id
),

counter as (
select at.id, 
case 
when '1' = all(status) then '1' 
when '3' = any(status) then '3' 
else status end as status
from at inner join bt on at.id=bt.a_id
)

select count (*) from counter where status='1'
```

Comment: Hi! 
I am not sure that it is an appropriate solution for us because the sorting of such a big volume of data will take too much time.

Comment: Hi. Sorting is performed after filtering and grouping data. Original script joins tables before any grouping, and this is the cause of long execution time

Comment: @Vad1m   Couldn't grouping first lead to a different (presumably wrong) answer, as the join could remove rows and so change the count?

Comment: @jjanes yes, it can lead to another answer if there are aggregation functions performing rows' count (count, avg, e.t.c.). But there aren't such ones. Regarding join clause: when joining tables, query's making table scan (if there's not any index on table). That means it compares each key's value in one table and key in other table. And this is near 4 * 10^15 operations (5.3 mln. records * 750 mln. records). This quantity should be reduced

Comment: @Vad1m  Yes, there are a lot of hash comparisons, but I don't see how it could be nearly as high as you list.  The 750 million are filtered down to 37 million before probing the hash.  And it doesn't compare every value on one side to every value on the other side, that is the whole point of a hash join.   If the hash join itself were slow, the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) would show that, and it doesn't. 98.8% of the hash join time is spent waiting for rows from its problem child.

Comment: You're right. The majority of time is spent for filtering, not for join The problem is in lack of index on table b. They should add indexes on columns 'l_id' and 'type_id'. I also moved filters to 'having' clause. This may reduce filtering time